# Android Studio terminal issue

Tags: shell, android-studio, terminal

I've installed Android Studio and it seems to work fine, but when I'm trying to use built-in Terminal I encounter the following problem - it just didn't give me an opportunity to print anything in it.

Example of terminal - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbosw.png

I've used Insert & Caps Lock, switch language, changed shell to Windows Powershell and nothing of listed helps, I'm still not able to print anything in terminal window. Can anyone provide any suggestion, how can I fix it?

**UPD**
Tried another IDE on IntelliJ platform and have the same issue with them.

Comment: Even I've the same problem. Following @PaoloV solutions works great. The issue is with the Windows 10 Mika.Ko